Accessing steamID64 using vanity URL, without steam API
I am building a Chrome extension and one of the features requires me to use steamID64.
The problem is that I don't have the steamID64 representation, sometimes I just have a vanity URL that looks like https://steamcommunity.com/id/%3CvanityURL%3E
So I need to convert from vanityURL to steamID64.
SteamWebAPI is not an option, it requires an API key, I don't have a server-side for my Chrome extension and I'm not going to buy one.
I tried looking for public APIs/Scraping, but they don't exist, or scraping isn't legal.
Any solution/idea? I need something legal since this project is gonna be published on GitHub

there's an official endpoint for this
Use http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=YOUR_API_KEY&vanityurl=VANITY_URL
You can get a Steam web api key from https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
